# how to redirect domain name with directory

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I have one project online and it on two diffrent domains 1)www.example.com and 2)www.example.co.in. now, I want to redirect

```
www.example.co.in/category/
```

to

```
www.example.com/ceramic+industry/
```

And I want to redirect it through *.htaccess* **or** from server. I tried from server that only redirect domain name not directory, and also tried from *.htaccess* where I can redirect only domain or only directory not when both domain and directory combine. My project in php. So, you can give advise if it's possible in php also.

Comment: It is possible through `.htaccess`, `server` and `php` all. We just need more information:- **category/** is a real folder or re-written URL? || you only want to redirect this URL or all url which starts with `category/`?

Comment: Why is this tagged for sql-server?

Comment: @Adarsh Rajput i just change folder category to ceramic+industry so i want to redirect all that start with category

Comment: @DivyeshJesadiya: what about my answer? and do you also want to redirect all other URL of `co.in` to `.com` as it is? only 'category/' should be redirect to 'ceramic+industry/'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add following rule in `.htaccess`(placed at root of website www.example.co.in):

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^category/(.*)$ http://www.example.com/ceramic+industry/$1 [L,R=301]
```

or use 302 for temporary redirects.

---

IF you also want to redirect whole `.co.in` website to `.com` THEN add next line(remember in `.com` website's .htaccess these two Rules should not be there.)

```
RewriteRule ^category/(.*)$ http://www.example.com/ceramic+industry/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

If for any reason you are bound to use same `.htaccess` on both site then use condition like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^category/(.*)$ http://www.example.com/ceramic+industry/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

**============================================================**

**Solution to your another query:**

This can be done by PHP. As I guessed all URL after `category/` is handled by one PHP page.

in that PHP page code this at top:

```
if(isset($_GET['company'])){
   $company=$_GET['company'];
   $companyNew=str_replace('_','+',$company);
   if($company!=$companyNew){
      header("location:/category/?company="+$companyNew,true,301);
      //header("location:/ceramic+industry/?company="+$companyNew,true,301);
      exit;
   }
}
```

Comment: it's done now i want to redirect www.example.co.in/category/?company=vijay_ceramic(anything with _(underscor)) to www.example.com/ceramic+industry/?company=vijay+ceramic(_(underscore) to +)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^your.first.domain$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://your.second.domain/$1 [R,L]
```

This will redirect, if your request contains existing directory name.

Answer to your comment. You can try this:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_FINISH} !^$
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^company=(.*)\_(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?company=%1+%2 [R,L,E=FINISH:1]
```

First two lines allow you to prevent infinite loop redirect.

Comment: it's done now i want to redirect www.example.co.in/category/?company=vijay_ceramic(anything with _(underscor)) to www.example.com/ceramic+industry/?company=vijay+ceramic(_(underscore) to +)